# how to use an object as a shared resource for multiple users

Tags: spring, servlets

I want to have a class that holds an arraylist of objects that will hold differnt objcts. Each user will b able to access these objcts according to the index number allotted to them. This index number corresponds to the object they are assigned.
Now i want to have a single instance of this class holding the arraylist which would be shared by all the user threads. I am using spring to declare a singleton objct fir this. But im confused as to where i should instantiate the application context so that i can achieve this. Please do help.

Comment: Where is the code you tried?

Comment: This is a very easy task, just try it by yourself, go back if you got some specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

The singleton is shared by all users. You can inject it anywhere you want.

Except if you have multiple instances of your application (for example, if you have a load balancer and 2 instances of your web application server)